# How to add spaces after comma in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have below function from which i was returning values, but now i want to add spaces after each commma.

Comment: Maybe add the value to the initial space from `accountObj`? `accountObj.name += account.account_name;` But then you will have a space before the first element.. :-?

Comment: i want to add spaces after comma in accounts column

Comment: Then try to do it right before the push, `accountObj.name += '  '`

Comment: tried bt its adding space before values not after comma

Comment: use (this.allLabel.split(',').join(', ')).trim()

Comment: So how are they added to the column? That is the missing part! Where is the Angular Template code?

Answer (score 1):

**Try Using:**

**split with `,` and join with `,`**

```js
var a = 'All,Where,When,Now,And';


var b = (a.split(',').join(', ')).trim();


console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = 'hello,world';
    string.replace(/,/g, ", ")
```

you can add using this replace function in your case:

```
getSchemaAccount(providerArr) {
    const accountNameArr = [];
    providerArr.forEach(provider => {
      if (provider.asset_accounts.length > 0) {
        provider.asset_accounts.forEach(account => {
          const accountObj = { name: ' ', disabledAccount: false };
          if (account.account_name && account.account_id !== this.allValue) {
            accountObj.name = account.account_name.replace(/,/g, ", "); <---- add this
          } else if (account.account_id === this.allValue) {
            accountObj.name = this.allLabel.replace(/,/g, ", ");  <---- add this
          } else {
            accountObj.name = account.account_id;
            accountObj.disabledAccount = true;
          }            
          accountNameArr.push(accountObj);
        });
      } 
    });
    if(accountNameArr.length === 0) {
      accountNameArr.push({ name: this.allLabel, disabledAccount: false });
    }  
    return accountNameArr;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using normal table to show your data and accounts is an array of objects ( since we dont have the exact structure of your data). In order to give space after comma you need to wrap you account name binding to span tag.

```
       <tr *ngFor="let provider of providerData">
            <td>{{provider.id}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let account of provider.accounts">
              <span class="mr-5">{{account.account_name}} </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

add below class at component level

```
.mr-5 {
 "margin-right:5px"
}
```